# Do I have to pay taxes on a home warranty refund check?

Tags: check, refund

I received a refund check from the home warranty service. Do I have to pay taxes for that. It a remediation check.

Comment: Different jurisdictions can handle tax matters differently. Please add information about which jurisdiction you are asking about.

Answer (score 5):

As a refund check, it is not taxable. If this is related to the Wells Fargo scandal, the bank is basically saying that they overcharged you in the first place, so it is not income, it's '[remediation](https://www.wellsfargo.com/help/customer-redress/)' for the overcharge.